# Polynomial Orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthogonality

I study Polynomial Orthogonality and in connection to Linear Algebra I visualize the concept this way :

- $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials
- Any polynomial $p(x)$ in the interval $[a,b]$ is a vector with **infinite coordinates** as $[a,b]$ contains an infinite amount of numbers $[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and it's coordinates are $(p(x_0),p(x_1),\dots,p(x_n))$
- The inner product of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is equal to : $f(x_0)*g(x_0)+f(x_1)*g(x_1)+\dots+f(x_n)*g(x_n)$
- The process above can also be expressed as : $\int_{x_0}^{x_n} f(x)*g(x) \,dx$

I got 3 questions though :

- Is there a better/more accurate way to visualize the concept described above?
- In most cases/examples I've seen writers limit themselves to the interval $[-1,1]$.Why is that? I tried some plotting and integration in Desmos an indeed in most cases only the interval $[-1,1]$ takes the inner product to $0$.
- Besides orthogonality and in connection to Linear Algebra is there a way to show that two polynomials over an interval $[a,b]$ are as vectors linearly indpendent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not how it works.

First, the set of polynomials with coefficients in a field $\Bbb K$ (for instance $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$) is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) over the field $\Bbb K$. A natural basis of this vector space is $(1,X,X^2,\dots)$. It's also possible to consider only polynomials of degree $\le n$, which is a finite dimensional vector space, of dimension $n+1$.

Given an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) of this vector space, it's then possible, using [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), to build an orthogonal basis.

So, it remains to find an inner product. A common way (but not the only one), is to define

$$\left<P,Q\right>=\int_a^bP(x)Q(x)w(x)dx$$

Where $a,b$ are fixed but arbitrary, and possibly infinite, and $w$ is a weight function. Of course, the integral must be convergent for any polynomial $P,Q$.

For instance, with $w=1$ and $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, you get [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). Examples on an unbounded interval include [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) and [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

More on this on Wikipedia:

- [Orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials)
- [Classical orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials)

---

To answer your last question: two polynomials are linearly independent if their quotient is not a constant. More generally, it's possible to check the linear independance of a set of $n$ polynomials, using for instance a [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant).

For this, you need an inner product: you may use one of those described above. It's also possible to use the fact that the vector space $\Bbb R_n[X]$polynomials of degree $\le n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ (using the values of these polynomials at $n+1$ points, thanks to the linearity of [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)), then use an inner product on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.